# Handling Press Back Button without reloading fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to press the **back button** and go back to previous **fragment**, without the entire fragment loading up every time. I've looked over **stackoverflow** but I haven't been able to find an answer yet. Currently, when I switch fragments, the different fragments overlap, even though the back button works as expected.

MainActivity.java

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag_container, new CatalogueFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Also in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="genericViewModel"
            type="MainActivity"/>
    </data>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#000"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/favourites_recycler"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frag_container"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/side_navbar"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix it.

1. You can set the background for `CatalogueFragment` view, I mean background for ViewGroup when you call `onCreateView` inside `CatalogueFragment`
2. Before call add Fragment you should get current Fragment by tag and make fragment transaction hide it.

```
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        if (!fragments.isEmpty()) {
            for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
                if (!fragment.isHidden()) {
                    transaction.hide(fragment);
                }
            }
        }
```